# VB.Net initializing datasets

Tags: vb.net, dataset

When did Microsoft start forcing datasets to be initialized with a "New" statement?  My company has a website that was started many years ago and a lot of the datasets were declared with a statement like

```
Dim someDataset as Dataset = Nothing
```

This code has worked for a long time but we recently started receiving errors stating Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: dataset.

I've done my best to update this old code but I'm not aware of any updates to the libraries we are using and I'm trying to identify what triggered this error to begin with.  Thank you

I'd like to emphasize that no changes were made to the code before the error started occurring as unlikely as that might sound.  It is a large app and datasets are used throughout it in a variety of ways.  It has been in production for many years and worked as expected before this error started occurring recently.

Comment: Such a change sounds very unlikely.  And it **completely** depends on what you're doing with the dataset.

Comment: VB has required instances since VB.Net.  There were some cases in VB6, and a small number in VB.Net, where the language provided default instances.  This was usually UI related though, I have no knowledge of this ever happening for `DataSet`

Comment: FWIW, `Dim someDataset as Dataset = Nothing` is redundant. You can leave of the ` = Nothing` part, and the result is the exact same IL.

Comment: But that code isn't where the error was thrown, was it? Somewhere between the declaration you have quoted above, and the point where the error is being thrown, there was another piece of code that instantiated the dataset, either directly, or by setting someDataset to the return value of a function that returned a dataset, such as a tableadapter or similar in your DAL. And that is what's changed; the dataset is no longer being instantiated.

Comment: The DAL is where the error was usually occurring.  Datasets being passed back to the UI weren't being initialized before they were loaded and returned.  Depending on the function, dataset were being built explicitly, or loaded from DatabaseFactory calls or sqlAdapters.  Not being the original developer I'm not sure why they weren't being initialized.  But what I don't understand is why this code has worked for so many years only to suddenly start sending errors messages when no changes had been published. I was hoping someone might have encountered a similar issue and could tell me the cause.

Answer (score 1):

That has not changed since Day 1 of .NET.  All reference types must be created with a `New` statement somewhere or else they will remain a null reference (`Nothing`).

It sounds like some other part of the app that used to create the dataset has been removed or changed so that it sometimes returns `Nothing`.

Comment: I know that's how it sounds but that would have required a change to be made in several hundred places where the application uses datasets

Comment: Would it?  Or could there be a few common places that those several hundred also reference?

Comment: I tried to find something in common with the functions populating the datasets that were returning errors.  I had hoped there might be a particular database or connection being used to populate the data that could be causing the problem, or a service they were all referencing.  After researching it for several days I couldn't find any 1 thing they had in common other than the datasets were not being initialized with a "New" statement before they were populated.  Adding that statement has fixed the problem, but it doesn't explain why the code has been running without errors for several years.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between declaring and instantiating.

This line declares a `DataSet`:

```
Dim myDataSet As DataSet
```

Note: Since you only declared a `DataSet` object, it is not set to an instance, therefore it is `Nothing`.

This line instantiates a `DataSet`:

```
myDataSet = New DataSet()
```

Often you will see the lines put together, like this:

```
Dim myDataSet = New DataSet()
```

If you only declare a `DataSet`, then you must be sure to check if it is `Nothing` before you use it, like this:

```
If myDataSet Is Not Nothing Then
    ' Use myDataSet because there is an instance of it
End If
```

Note: You should ALWAYS check if the return type of a `Function` is `Nothing` or not.

Comment: That is exactly what we did to correct the problem.  We went through and found every instance of a dataset that was not being initialized with a new statement.  What I don't understand is why it worked without doing that before.

Comment: @user2718511 - unfortunately, I believe that is going to be impossible for us to answer. :-(

Comment: @user2718511 - you may want to investigate the `Null Object` pattern.

Comment: What is the Null Object pattern?

Comment: @user2718511 - read [Null Object Pattern In C#](http://danielshitrit.blogspot.com/2011/11/best-practices-null-object-pattern-in-c.html), I realize that you are using VB.NET, but this will give an idea of how to use this pattern.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that the code that caused me problems was written following best practices and in the future I will do my best to update things correctly.  But the code ran.  No one went in and removed every line of code that initialized a dataset properly.  It just stopped working for some unknown reason that I would like to identify if I can before it happens on another server